# Finding very top and bottom peaks of data using Matlab

Tags: matlab, minimum

I have a set data and I'd like to find the upper and lower peaks of it.
In Matlab, I am trying `findpeaks` command, but the result is strange.

Here is my simple code:

```
 [pks,locs] = findpeaks(Data);
 plot(locs,pks,'or')
```

and here is the result:
[image]

Can someone guide me on how I can find only the very top and very bottom peaks of the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the additional input `MinPeakProminence` to tell Matlab to look only for, yeah well prominent peaks.

```
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(Data,'MinPeakProminence',4);
 plot(locs,pks,'or')
```

You can play with the parameter and see what works best for you.